# Add letter at the beginning of string

Tags: r, string

I am trying to change the name of some columns in my data using str_c function ( after installing "stringr" package). Column names are as follow:

```
> x 
   a  b  c  d
```

I need to change the the "c" and "d" with "Aa" and "Ab". So instead of writing the full column names in my command, I will use the following structure:

```
colnames(x[,3:4])<-str_c(colnames(x[,1:2], "A")
```

However, the result shows the "A" at the end not the beginning of the name. So how to put the "A" at the beginning to get the following:

```
 > x
    a  b  Aa  Ab
```

Comment: You should document that `str_c` comes from a package that needs to be available and loaded. This question will not be helpful to someone who is just starting out in R and doesn't understand that this function is really just copying the base function `paste0`. It's also going to confuse them (and possibly you) when you go to use the `$` function and discover that it doesn't honor column names that begin with numerals unless the name is quoted.

Comment: @BondedDust all have been fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question and this is for displaying a "column name", then you should swap the order in your expression, this

```
colnames(x[,3:4])<-str_c(colnames(x[,1:2], "A")
```

should be

```
colnames(x[,3:4])<-str_c("A", colnames(x[,1:2])
```

**Note** column names with a leading digit won't work with the `$` function unless the name is quoted. So "A" works fine with '$' function but "1" needs the name to be quoted.

Comment: Yes it may work, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea. I think appropriate warnings should be given since `1a` is not a valid R name.

Comment: Sorry @Elliott maybe I missed something but I do not see how this could work. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24867333/766828.